# How can I uninstall all the packages I've installed today?

Tags: apt, software-center, uninstall

I was trying to get musepack encoder support built into ffmpeg today, and I inadvertently broke a few things but I'm not sure exactly which package I installed which broke them.  How can I remove ALL packages I installed today, and start again from scratch more carefully?

I can see a list of them in "Ubuntu Software Center" under today's date in the "History", but I don't want to go through uninstalling them one-by-one, because there are hundreds to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file `/var/log/apt/history.log` has what you need. Take a look at the answer: [How to reinstall many removed packages at once?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50622/how-to-reinstall-many-removed-packages-at-once) it's a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 16):

```
grep -e `date +%Y-%m-%d` /var/log/dpkg.log | awk '/install / {print $4}' | uniq | xargs apt-get -y remove
```

found on [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1858/remove-todays-installed-packages) worked fine for me

Comment: This will remove only packages installed by dpkg, not by apt.

Comment: I just tested the `grep -e \`date +%Y-%m-%d\` /var/log/dpkg.log | awk '/install / {print $4}' | uniq` output, was exactly the packages I installed using `apt-get` today!! nice script buddy, +1.

Comment: You may need add one another parameter to `apt-get`: `apt-get -y --allow-remove-essential remove`

Comment: `E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?` even with `sudo`

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: Nala is still in a development stage, and is not recommended for any professional use.*

##### For `apt` packages

If you're ready to use the command line to install new packages, it's possible to get an easy undo feature with the more modern `apt` front-end called `nala` (for 22.04 you have to enable the "universe" repository). *Note: This will only work for `apt`/`.deb` packages.*

```
sudo apt install nala
```

From this point, use `nala` to install new packages on your system, using:

```
sudo nala install <package-name>
```

Leave security updates etc. to the `unattended-upgrades` package.

Now, when you run the command `nala history`, you get a list of the commands run with nala, including installed packages. To filter only new installations, use:

```
nala history | grep install
```

An added bonus of the history feature is that you can undo any step in the history, so that you can easily reverse package installation procedures. This can be done by issuing the command:

```
sudo nala history undo <ID>
```

Where `<ID>` is the ID number of the transaction in the history list you want to undo.

##### For `snap` packages

Snap has its own "undo" feature, where you can easily revert to the previously installed version. This is done with:

```
sudo snap revert <package-name>
```

In case you want to revert to a specific revision of a snap package, this can be stated as well;

```
sudo snap revert <package-name> --revision <rev ID>
```

For snaps, also [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198022/how-to-run-a-previous-version-of-a-snap-package).