# Ubuntu 20.04.02 (Focal) OS rollback is possible?

Tags: 22.04

I'm running the Ubuntu 20.04.02 (Focal) version and its production environment. Planning to apply the latest OS patches to these servers. Kindly suggest, that we roll back all upgrades and back to the earliest.

**Example**: Centos or Redhat, we have options like "yum history undo ". Do we have the same option in Ubuntu?

I don't want to downgrade each package one by one. Because since we are in production, any impact they ask us to roll back all recent changes. Kindly suggest.

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"

$ uname -r
5.4.0-124-generic
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Snapshot and rollback of apt-installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213029/snapshot-and-rollback-of-apt-installed-packages)

Comment: Above answer doesn't meet my requirement. Kindly let me know the commands to rollback the recent installed patches.

Comment: "Your requirement" is not possible using the default tools, but the thread I linked to gives several solutions. If this does not meet "your requirement", please write a new production-ready application to serve this requirement, and share with the community. Thanks. 

Comment: Also, see my [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68460/how-can-i-uninstall-all-the-packages-ive-installed-today/). What you're looking for can be done with [`nala`](https://gitlab.com/volian/nala), but since I don't consider `nala` production ready, I wouldn't normally recommend it for your usecase (since you explicitly state it's a production environment).

Comment: The easiest options are via whatever backup strategy you put in places; with some file-systems (eg. *btrfs*) you'll have more options than others, but again those need to be setup before hand, in order to use them. If your details are correct (20.04.2) you've not applied security fixes since August 2021 so I hope your system is off-line (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/08/27/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 20.04.3, but installed systems upgraded **before** this date)

Comment: I use timeshift for this purpose. For my desktops, I take a snapshot once a day; for my servers, once an hour.